# Matlab imshow function border tight not working under small size image

Tags: matlab, border

By default, when imshow displays an image in a figure, it surrounds the image with a gray border. You can change this default and suppress the border using the 'border' parameter, as shown in the following example.

```
imshow('moon.tif','Border','tight')
```

[image]

But, I recently found that border tight will stop working when the matrix is smaller than approximately 125-130 thresholding

Please try these two Matlab command and you will see the difference

```
imshow(rand(130,130),'Border','tight')  % works! no grey boundary at all
imshow(rand(120,120),'Border','tight')  % not working! grey boundary appears
```

Here are my reuslts:
[image]

Is that a bug? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem by writing the function below

```
function outputimg = removeBorder(inputimg, size)
outputimg = zeros(size,size,3);
grayscale = rgb2gray(inputimg);
%Find upper left element in foreground
[x,y] = find(grayscale~=204,1);
outputimg = inputimg(x:x+size-1,y:y+size-1,:);
```

Observing that the grays region (border) pixel intensity is always 204, basically, it detects the first element position that is not equal to 204, that will be the upper left point of the square. Then, since we know the square size of efficient region, we can finally crop the matrix to remove all the border.

The ONLY drawback of the code that may fail is that the foreground cannot contain pixel value that is exactly 204 where in my case, it is acceptable. I also tried to count border size in each side, but found the size is not balanced for some reason, not sure why.

Thank you for @ Benoit_11's help.